# Wordpress blog + Laravel with SEO friendly urls

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, laravel-4

I have a website with Laravel, I am starting a wordpress blog on the website with url.

http://abcd.com/blog

I have uploaded wordpress blog in the public directory of laravel. To exclude wordpress blog from laravel htaccess rules, I have added following line in my laravel htaccess

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(blog)
```

It works fine, but when I enabled SEO friendly urls for the blog to make urls as

```
http://abcd.com/blog/sample-post/
```

it gives internal error when I try to view a blog post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as you have the following two files, you should be just fine:

**`DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`** (where the document root is your Laravel `public` directory):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**`DOCUMENT_ROOT/blog/.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Of course, I've trimmed down the defaults - just showing what should be in each file.

So, you don't actually need to exclude the directory at all. That's already done with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`.